# C++ passing pointer reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I want to pass pointer object to function by reference. I don't know If I am doing correct as It is not working as per below code. Please help me.

```
class Base
{
    public:  
    int x;
    void print()// function prints x value
    {
        cout<<x;
    }
    void call_print(Base **base) //function call print function
    {
        base->print();
    }
};
int main()
{
    Base *b = new Base; // creating pointer object
    b->call_print(&b); // passing pointer by reference
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) that is not a reference, but a pointer to a pointer 2) either way, not required unless you want to change what is pointed to, and `base->print` won't work with `Base **` 3) why even use `new` (and you don't `delete` anyway).

Comment: Remove an one asterisk in `call_print` declaration: `void call_print(Base *base)`. Also call `b->call_print(b)` in `main` function.

Comment: If you actually intend a double-pointer:
 if (base) { (*base)->print(); }

Comment: The person says they want to pass a poiner by pointer essentially - if that is what they want, they can do it

Comment: Is there a use case you need to write code like this for, or is it just for fun?

Comment: What's the point of not calling `print` directly?

Comment: But what if I want to call one function inside other.This is what I tried. yeah I forgot to delete that object. Even when I use one asterisk it throws error.

Comment: It is not for fun obviously. As I said I just wanted to call one function inside another.

Comment: "I want to pass pointer object to function by reference" - then pass a pointer by reference: `Base *& base` as your parameter and simply `b` from the caller.

Comment: I just made it simple to understand. Actually I want to change the value of x which is declared in some class through a function of another class.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig finally I am able to execute my code.

Comment: "It is not for fun obviously. As I said I just wanted to call one function inside another." - not obvious at all, and also not what was said. There are many ways to write this; requesting one solution and expecting a mind-reading approach is rather frustrating. Double-pointers are often passed in Microsoft interfaces; it might actually be an attempt to understand double-pointers.

Comment: The source of the confusion in this comment string is that your phrasing "pass pointer object to function by reference" actually means something very specific in C++, but it's not idiomatic in basic C++.  It does not appear from your comments that you actually want that specific C++ construct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing the object by "reference" in the sense that you still have access to the original object through the parameter, but note that `base` in `call_print()` is a pointer to the object being passed in, not the *actual* object. You still have to dereference the pointer if you want access to the object passed in:

```c++
(*base)->print();
```

C++ introduced actual references that are syntactic sugar upon what you have to do with pointers/double-pointers. For example:

```c++
void call_print(Base*& base)
{ base->print(); }

b->call_print(b);
```

Also, the use of a double pointer or reference seems unnecessary since you don't need to modify the pointer in any way. Why not just take in the pointer itself?

```c++
void call_print(Base* base)
{ base->print(); }

b->call_print(b);
```

And lastly, you don't need to pass `b` in as an argument to its own method. A pointer to the `Base` object is accessible through `this`:

```c++
void call_print()
{
    print(); /* or this->print() */
}

b->call_print();
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple note: don't use naked pointers, take advantage of C++11 facilities: std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr are even better, for resource management sake, and you can write something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> base_ptr(new Base());
base_ptr->call_print();
//no delete, unique_ptr deletes itself automatically
```

and for Base class, you have to write:

```
void call_print() //function call print function
{
    this->print();
}
```

because you don't need to pass to the same object, the reference to itself.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base
{
    public:  
    int x;
    void print()
    {
        cout<<x<<endl;
    }
};
class Base2
{
    public:
    void change_value(Base *&base) 
    {
        base->x = 5;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Base *b = new Base;
    Base2 b2;
    b2.change_value(b);
    b->print();
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to do. Thank you all for helping me.It is working now :)

Comment: You can change `x` if you pass a non-pointer `Base` by reference! (in other words, you don't need pointers at all, just C++ references)